# voltage selector circuit for programming microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, transistors, switches

I have a microcontroller that has a VPP pin which requires 12 volts to enable programming mode, 5 volts for normal mode, and 0 volts for reset, and I want to achieve all these modes without manually connecting the pin to each of the voltage sources.

So far, I'm able to control whether it receives 0 volts or one other voltage source simply by connecting VCC to a resistor and to collector of an NPN. The emitter of the same NPN is grounded, and If I apply 5 volts to the base, then the output at collector is at zero. Otherwise its at VCC.

Can I somehow achieve a similar effect with two NPN transistors where they both control the same VPP pin on the microcontroller without blowing anything up?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your current solution, VPP (when ON) is fed through a resistor. I don't think this is a good idea. If this resistor has a too high value and the MCU draws significant current from VPP, the voltage drop will be too high and the MCU may reset itself. But if you lower the resistor value, the current wasted when VPP is 0V will become too high. Instead, you should feed VPP through a PNP transistor.

Anyway, here is a basic solution, just using simple components:

[image]

You can choose whathever voltage to feed VPP with (either 12V, 5V, or GND) by setting the corresponding control input line to high level. There is nothing really particular in this circuit: for both the 12V and 5V paths, there is a NPN + PNP couple that act as a level shifter. Then, for the GND path, just the NPN as you initially did. The only trick is the D1 diode to prevent backfeed of the 12V to the 5V supply and reverse biasing the 5V PNP emitter, when VPP is 12V. Use a schottky diode for lower drop.

Note: *do not* set both one of SET_xV *and* SET_GND to high level at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

put 3 switching element in the path of VPP pin to 3 voltage source,connect their output to each other to VPP, then wire switches enable pins to the 2->4 Demultiplexer.connect decoders input to your controller device and choose one of the voltage sources each time by choosing
[image]

Comment: So I could get a 3-to-one-line multiplexer and put 5 volts as input and 12 volts as another input? I'm assuming I'll need the cmos 4000 series chips? but I don't want to blow anything up. If there's an answer involving NPN transistors, then I'll go more for that.